# how to accept all date formats in C# over aws server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In my local environment when i am doing conversion like below i am able to convert datesince to yyyy-MM-dd format

```
string datesince="5/11/18" or "11/5/18" or "5-11-18" or "11-5-18" or "5/11/2018";
 DateTime Formatdate=   Convert.ToDateTime(datesince).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

But on production environment it is not working so i am using below solution

```
string[] formats = new string[8] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yy", "dd-MM-yy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "MM/dd/yy", "MM-dd-yy" };
   bool flag = DateTime.TryParseExact(datesince, formats, new CultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, out Formatdate);
```

but giving false ...how i can handle this situation

Comment: A word of warning: What if the date you're given is `01/02/2018`? How do you know whether that's the first of February or the second of January?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, for that i can tell first is month and then second is date part and third one is year

Comment: You can't tell that unless you know the local for the date. I can see from your list of formats that you are trying to support both dd/MM/yyyy AND MM/dd/yyyy, which never makes sense.

Comment: Are you trying to get format based on user's browser, ie. users local settings, or user is able to type date in any format (ie. same user would be able to pass yyyy-MM-dd and dd/MM/yyyy)?

Comment: @Caldazar,yes i am formatting based on user's browser

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
string language = "gb-GB"; //Or whatever is your default

//Detect User's Language.
if (Request.UserLanguages != null)
{
   //Set the Language.
   language = Request.UserLanguages[0];
}
//Set the Culture.
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(d1);
```

After that, just set CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture to what's your default.